# jQuery transparent dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I've come across this website:

[link](http://mmminimal.com/)

I was curious as to if there are any jQuery plugins out there currently that would generate this effect.

The effects I am looking for is the arrow, and the semi transparency. Or if you could point me to a similar direction, it would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about styling, not a plugin.  Looking at the source, [a simple drop-down menu plugin](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/) is being used.

As for the styling, you should be able to apply a similar look to any menu with just a few CSS rules.  [Take a look at the #navagation section in the css from the site for inspiration](http://mmminimal.com/wp-content/themes/mmm/style.css).  You might learn a thing or two ;)